# Trouble obtaining average to an array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, average

I am trying to get an average of an array and I found this code during my research.

```
int myArray[] = {1,2,3};
     Arrays.stream(myArray).average();
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

When I run it, the results come up as

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I'm new at java and I feel like there's something obvious that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Well, you're just printing the array, not the average.

Comment: Stream operations typically do **not at all** modify the "thing" on which they were created. They return a **result** to you, which your code just throws away.

Comment: @GhostCat so it's not possible to find the average with a Stream operation?

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to print the result. `Arrays.stream(myArray).average().ifPresent(System.out::println);`

Comment: @user7 awesome. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the original Array.

To print the calculated array add the next line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(myArray).average().getAsDouble());
```

Output:

> 2.0

Comment: Though this will work for the OP's input, this will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the input stream is empty

Comment: Indeed, but he's not asking about validation

Comment: I did not complain about your solution. Wanted to make it generic enough for all cases

Answer (score -1):

You are just printing only the array, Instead, you can do this.

```
int myArray[] = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(myArray).average().getAsDouble()));
```

OR

```
int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
OptionalDouble ans = Arrays.stream(myArray).average();
System.out.println(ans.getAsDouble());
```

> Here,OptionalDouble is a container object which may or may not contain
>   a double value. If a value is present, isPresent() will   return true
>   and getAsDouble() will return the value.